# Should I @-mention users in my question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been seeing a lot of people replying with blockquotes in the initial question like this:

---

### @username

> Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

I clearly said that

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does not work

---

I was just wondering if I should encourage this kinda stuff?

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you mean. Can you link to an example? Are you asking whether it makes sense to reply to someone *in a question*? For example, if user A asks a question, user B posts an answer saying they need to do something, and user A edits their question replying to user B that they've tried what they suggested?

Comment: Yeah @slhck that is what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put yourself into the position of a visitor who has the same problem as you and stumbles across your question on Super User. Now, in order for them to understand whom you're addressing, they would have to read all answers first.

I guess it would make more sense if you simply stated what didn't work, without mentioning a particular user. It's not like they're going to get a notification from your @-mention.

If you want to refer to multiple solutions that were posted as answers, perhaps you could write:

> I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> as user @foo suggested, but that didn't work.

You could then comment on the answer of that user in order for them to receive a notification in their inbox.

Comment: I totally agree!